# I have an array with 20 values. I want to display the values on a segment controller 3 items at a time with a more titled segment

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

On clicking on the more segment the segment controller should recreate itself with the next 3 values from the array and so on. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Do this.

Take and integer to hold the no. of times More button as been tapped.

_noOfTimes = 0;

Now when More button is tapped, load data from your array as such

```
- (void)method:(id)sender {
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(_noOfTimes * (length - 1), length); // length will be 3 in your case "1 back + 3 items + 1 more". Do the reverse when back button is pressed. decrease value of _noOfTimes first though ;)
    NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];

    NSArray *tempArray = [tempArray objectsAtIndexes:indexSet];

    //now change title of the segment controllers accordingly

    //and in the end
    _noOfTimes ++;
}
```

try it out this way. :)

Comment: But I want to recreate the whole segment controller if 'more' segment is clicked. In that way the next segment controller should have a 'previous' segment at the first index

Comment: okey, u dont need to recreate it .. To insert previous button, just increase the number of segments by inserting segment, when u click more for first time. then change the title values of corresponding segmentIndexes. When you want to remove any segment there is also api. Refere to `UISegmentedControl` documentation. And yes, adjust the provided code according to your requirements. :)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply but actually I need to follow a particular spec which demands this recreation.